# How to hide recently viewed products from specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, php

In my Magento v1.9.1.0 CE I want to edit the recently viewed file so that is does not show any recently viewed products from a specific parent category and all its sub categories.

Meaning say I have a parent category called 'Members only' category and a sub category in that parent category called 'tshirts'. If I then view any items in the 'Members only' or the 'tshirts' subcategory I do not want them to show up in that persons recently viewed items listing.

I am thinking I need to edit the file app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/template/reports/product_viewed.phtml file
to have an if statement that looks for the category id and then have an if statement that says if the category id == xyz then show an epty

tag else show the regular

tag with the product info.

However I am not sure how to get the category and or subcategory id from the product that would be showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to edit the template you mentioned, this is the if that you are talking about :) ->

```
<?php if (!array_intersect($_item->getCategoryIds(), array(categoryid3, categoryid3, categoryid3))): ?> //paste it below <?php foreach ($_products as $_item): ?>
```

and close if with `<?php endif; ?>` above `<?php endforeach; ?>`.